# Bootstrap Modal from PHP generated table list - Pass in values from list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple HTML table that I generated from a PHP call to my database:

```
 <?php    
 foreach($records as $record){
     $staffName = $availability->getField('fullName') ;
     $staffMobile = $availability->getField('cell') ;   
}
```

I then display the table with a link on the name to a Bootstrap modal:

```
<tr>
 <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><?php echo $staffName; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $staffMobile ;?>Mobile Number</td>
 </tr>
```

I would like the modal that appears to have a button to be able to call and SMS the staff member in the list. My modal at the moment appears:

```
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Contact Staff</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Call</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">SMS</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I would like the Call and SMS buttons to reference using this format:

```
tel:<?php echo $staffMobile ;?>
sms:<?php echo $staffMobile ;?>
```

but I can't work out a way to link each individual $staffMobile value to the modal which only has one instance.

Have been struggling for this for a few hours now and not making any progress - not even sure if this is possible